# Print a DataGridView

Tags: printing, datagridview, reportviewer, rdlc

I want print a DataGridView with report viewer & RDLCs.
Actually I want a document about RDLC & print.
Please help me.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is about printing datagrid view then have a look at this codeproject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridDrawer.Net.aspx)

If not printing or you want to know about reportviewer control and rdlc and printing then msdn is the best place for you.